abi: attempting to unmarshal an empty string while arguments are expected
After updating go-etherum from github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum v1.10.22 to v1.13.15
My contracts started printing out error
abi: attempting to unmarshal an empty string while arguments are expected
Should i regenerate abi codes? I really dont get the idea go-ethereum complaining, whereas everything worked like a charm before.

I have regenerated abi and bin file with latest go-ethereum, but still running into same issue.

Can you provide the function source code of the contract?

need more details on the source code
